# Expose few property of class at runtime in WCF service

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf, wcf-data-services

I have a class for ex User class in WCF service, In that i have 10 properties like Fname, Lname, ServiceStatus, ErrorMessage etc.

Now there is method in service who retrieve the user info by giving the valid Json input and gives output in Json format (Here I am exposing user class object).

Now my problem: - Now when i expose this user class then i got the all properties  in json output. There were few cases where i don't want to expose all properties. In some cases I want to expose only two properties, or in few cases all properties. I want to do this to make JSON Output more clear.

Is it Possible in WCF? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Either don't put `[DataMember`] attribute or add `[IgnoreDataMember]` Attribute to that property to which you do not want to expose.

Comment: Thanks pawan, But i would like to do it at run time. Will it be possible??